# Relational algebra and union

Tags: relation-algebra

Consider a database consisting of the relations, where the primary key of each relation is bolded.

sailors (**sid**, sname, rating, age)

boats (**bid**, bname, color)

reserved (**sid**, bid, date)

Find all sailor id's of sailors who have a rating of at least 8 or reserved boat 103.

Answer given is:

$π_{\mbox{sid}}\left [σ_{\mbox{rating} \geq 8} (S) \right ] \cup π_{\mbox{sid}} \left [ σ_{\mbox{bid}=103} (R) \right ]$

Why can we use a union in the solution? The selection of all sailors with a rating of at least 8 would return rows with all 4 attributes but the projection of sailors who rented boat 103 would only return the sid, right? I thought the two sets had to have the same arity.

Comment: When you project you just get the sid's.  So you are taking the union of two sets of sid's.

Comment: @DisplayName Oh I guess I'm reading the answer wrong? It's taking the union of π sid(σ rating >= 8 (S)) and π sid [σ bid=103 (R)] ???

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you project you just get the sid's. So you are taking the union of two sets of sid's.